# Pdf Rotation Issues

Tags: php, yii2

I have issues in rotating pdf cell test in vertical. I don't want to add new rotated cell. I want to rotate existing cell text. I'm using Yii and tcpdf library.

I'm currently using :

```
        $pdf->Rotate(-90);
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,'22-01-2020',1,1,'L',0,'');
        $pdf->StopTransform()
```

which add a new rotated cell. But I want to rotate a existing cell. Kindly help me.

Comment: I saw your "comment" on my answer(review edit), use start transform where the cell is located.

Comment: I have used the start transform. It do work for new cell. My question is how to change the rotation of existing cell text.

Comment: _"existing cell text."_ It mean you edit a exist pdf or what? it's not clear.

Comment: I'm calling a test.php file which contain the html and i'm converting that html into pdf using tcpdf. Html has already content in which i want few text in vertical shape.

Comment: I edit my answer with rotate of writecell.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `$pdf->StartTransform();` where is the cell you want rotate like:

```
$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->Rotate(-90);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'22-01-2020',1,1,'L',0,'');  // CELL YOU WANT
$pdf->StopTransform()
```

Edit with your code:

```
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->AddPage();  
$mydata = array('name' => 'test');      
$postdata = http_build_query($mydata);
$opts = array('http' =>
   array(
   'method'  => 'POST',
   'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'content' => $postdata
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$html_path = 'testpdf.php';
$html = file_get_contents($html_path, false, $context);
$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->Rotate(-90);
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->StopTransform();
$pdf->lastPage();
$fileNL = 'test.pdf';
$pdf->Output($fileNL, 'I');
```

**Edit 2

Code for rotate just the first column:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rotate').css('height', $('.rotate').width());
});
```

```css
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
tr:nth-of-type(5) td:nth-of-type(1) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.rotate {
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* IE6,IE7 */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  /* IE8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  /* Standard */
  transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='rotate'>90 DEGREE ROW</div>
    </td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='rotate'>90 DEGREE ROW</div>
    </td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='rotate'>90 DEGREE ROW</div>
    </td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>O</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But these lines add a new rotated cell date. I want to change the rotation of a existing cell.

Comment: <!----testpdf.php---->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="sales-section">
                        <tr class="sales-heading">
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Date & Initial</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="id">
                            <td class="tbl-col-xs tbl-count">2</td>
                            <td class="tbl-col-md" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);">07/12/2020</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

Comment: Html code in testpdf.php which is a view file. Where i can not use the $pdf variable.

Comment: if you want rotate in html use css like `#myTable { transform:rotate(270deg);}` else use my code to rotate all `$pdf->writehtml`

Comment: It will rotate the entire pdf vertical. I want the rotate only 1 column.

Comment: Only 1 column of html table?

Comment: Yes, Only 1 column of table. I hope you understand my query. I want the date in vertical. All other text will be displayed normal.

Comment: Will it work for pdf? Rotation comes fine in the html page but when we convert it in pdf. Rotation doesn't work.

Comment: I will try later

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer. Can you please guide me how i can achieve this.

Comment: When i have time i will replace you code can you post all code ?

Comment: That is the all code. You can post with any example where we can rotate particular text which is already written in HTML form. Basically we are converting HTML into PDF.